# GSKILL RAM the last letter - what does it really mean?

Tags: memory

If you are searching for RAM using a QVL you know how hard it is to get exact matches... While searching I looked up GSKILL's naming convention which is NICE, relatively easy to follow... Sometimes the last letter might be different then what you searched for, an ADDED A, B, or C. They say quote 
"*If there is a "A", "B" or "C" as the third letter of the series, such as "TZB" or "RKB", then it typically designates a different CL timing value when compared to the original model without the "B" in the third letter."
What does this mean? and what are the timings of these modules?

Comment: cl timing on older laptops is crucial, they need to match, no so much on newer models. Ran into this just last week. tried to upgrade an older HP laptop, ordered PC2 ram, but it wont even post, bios doesn't like the timings.

Answer (score 0):

CL timing is for older laptops that need/require very specific timings, if you got the wrong timing one they usually wont post. I believe this isn't much of an issue these days and is mainly just for older laptops.

Just looked at the comment Moab made and its about the same thing, if he posts a answer id suggest marking his as the accepted one